# JavaScript - How to increase count

Tags: javascript, servicenow

when I give the variable which is an IP(10.31.68.0/22) with the current below script it will return
Output: **10.31.68.1 - 10.31.68.10**

```
var network = '10.31.68.0/22';
var IPstart = network.toString().substring(0,network.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".1";                      
var IPend = network.toString().substring(0,network.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".10";               
var excludename = IPstart+"-"+IPend;
```

I am looking for something (Output) like below. 68 placeholder should increase by +1 like below.

10.31.68.1 - 10.31.68.10

10.31.69.1 - 10.31.69.10

10.31.70.1 - 10.31.70.10

10.31.71.1 - 10.31.71.10

Comment: split/loop/join

Comment: [JavaScript function to parse a CIDR Range string into beginning and ending IPv4 Addresses](https://gist.github.com/binarymax/6114792)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This looks kind of related but not exactly. Could help me more on this@ja

Comment: @Rakesh Just to confirm, you want the 3rd part to be incremented by 1 and the 4th part to be appended with a 0? Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @AjayGupta. Yes 3rd part to be incremented 4th part will be 1 and 10 like in the output. When we hit the execute output should look exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need to split and join the values with loop

```js
var network = '10.31.68.0/22';
    var IPstart = network.toString().substring(0,network.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".1";
    var IPend = network.toString().substring(0,network.lastIndexOf('.')) + ".10";
    var excludename = IPstart+"-"+IPend;
    var upToNumber=4;
    for(var i=0;i<upToNumber;i++){
        var res_ipstart = IPstart.split(".");
    res_ipstart[2]=parseInt(res_ipstart[2]) + i;
    var ip_start = res_ipstart.join(".");

        var res_ipend = IPend.split(".");
    res_ipend[2]=parseInt(res_ipend[2]) + i;
    var ip_end = res_ipend.join(".");

    var output=ip_start+"-"+ip_end;
    console.log(output);
    }
```

Comment: Thank very much @Dinesh. Can you please tell me how do I stop this loop at 4th line which means 10.31.71.1-10.31.71.10?

Comment: @Rakesh use  var upToNumber=4; insted of  var upToNumber=10;

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```js
/* Remove the slash */
let rawIp = "10.31.68.1/22";
let rawIpParts = rawIp.split("/");

/* Split the new ip */
let ip = rawIpParts[0];
let ipParts = ip.split(".")

/* Append 0 */
ipParts[3] = ipParts[3].concat("0");

/* Output Array */
let output = []

/* Loop and increment */
for(let index = 0; index <= 4; index++) {
  ipParts[2] = 1 + +ipParts[2];
  output.push(ipParts.join("."));
}

/* Print */
console.log(output);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are correct but missing 

10.31.69.1 - 10.31.69.10


10.31.70.1 - 10.31.70.10


10.31.71.1 - 10.31.71.10

Comment: You could simply use a loop to achieve that.

Comment: @Rakesh Edited my answer